# Are there branches of mathematics that are unique to String Theory?

Tags: mathematical-physics, string-theory

I have read that String Theory has developed “new” math but the sources do not specifically identify the math. My question: are there branches of mathematics that are unique to String Theory? By unique I mean not used in fundamental theories such as: classical field theory, relativity and quantum mechanics.

Comment: I just stopped by and would like to share the viewpoint that you may want to specify "unique" you want in a more detailed manner; otherwise it is possible for this interesting question to get closed. Just two cents. Mathematics is like a skyscraper; so it is difficult to separate one branch completely from others :).

Comment: Maybe you can check out the book "enumerative geometry and string theory." Disclaimer: I don't know anything about this topic.

Comment: In the Physics StackExchange (What are some significant contributions of string theory to other fields of physics?)  Lubos Motl says:String theory is the framework in which mirror symmetry was discovered; mathematicians have converted it into a sub discipline of algebraic geometry that is studied by rigorous mathematical tools these days. Quite generally, much of algebraic geometry, especially topics related to Calabi-Yau manifolds, topology of higher-dimensional manifolds, K-theory, are using lots of tools that were first invented with the help of string theory ...